# javax.el.ELException: Function ':empty' not found

Tags: jsp, el

The JSP code is:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty(selectedTabItem)}">
        <c:set var="titleParamName" value="home-title"/>
        <c:set var="descriptionParamName" value="home-description"/>
        <c:set var="keywordsParamName" value="home-keywords"/>
    </c:when>
```

When I run the project in Tomcat server, I get an error as

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /pages/home.jsp(16,1) "${empty(selectedTabItem)}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Function ':empty' not found

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parentheses. It's a keyword, not a function.

```
<c:when test="${empty selectedTabItem}">
```